# Split file based off of two columns in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited file that I would like to split into smaller files based off of two columns. My data looks like the following:

> ```
>     360.40   hockey   james  april  expensive
>     1200.00  hockey   james  may    expensive
>     124.33   baseball liam   april  cheap
>     443.12   soccer   john   may    moderate
> ```

I want to parse these rows by the third and fifth columns.

The end result would be three different files named after the third and fifth columns like this:

> james-expensive.tsv liam-cheap.tsv john-moderate.tsv

In each of those files I want only the first value in the row associated with that name/expense type. So in james-expensive.tsv for exmaple,the file would contain one column:

> 360.40
>
> 1200.00

I thought maybe some sort of awk script or sed script may be able to solve this, but I'm not quite sure where to start.

If it seems like a bad idea to do this with either awk or sed, that would help to know too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $1 > $3 "-" $5 ".tsv" }' your_file
```

Result:

```
$ for F in *.tsv; do echo "---- $F ----"; cat "$F"; done
---- james-expensive.tsv ----
360.40
1200.00
---- john-moderate.tsv ----
443.12
---- liam-cheap.tsv ----
124.33
```

Update for `nawk`:

```
awk '{ f = $3 "-" $5 ".tsv"; print $1 > f }' your_file
```

Prevent too many opened files:

```
awk '{ f = $3 "-" $5 ".tsv" } !a[f]++ { printf "" > f } { print $1 >> f; close(f) }' your_file
```

Comment: Do you know if OS X awk would work? Getting this `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {print $1 > $3 >>>  "-" <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Comment: When I run the above awk command I get the following error: `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 {print $1 > $3 >>>  "-" <<<`

Comment: You're probably using `nawk`. Workaround is to store the filename first to a variable: `awk '{f = $3 "-" $5 ".tsv"; print $1 > f}' your_file`

Comment: One last question, is there a limit to the size of file this will work with? My file for example would have a couple hundred thousand rows.

Comment: @GrahamJackson There's no limit to data size however the number of target files may have to be considered. If it's many it would need adjustments. Can you test it on a temporary directory if shows an error?

Comment: I get an error that says: `james-expensive.tsv makes too many open files`

Comment: Would this fix it? `close(f)` after the print?

Comment: Yes `close(f)` is part of it but `>` would truncate the file for every loop so you have to use `>>`. Still `>>` would add data to existing files so you have to truncate the file at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag perl but here is a oneliner:

```
perl -lane '`echo "$F[0]" >> $F[2]-$F[4].tsv`' file
```